# Display Advanced Custom field on Wordpress Taxo Term

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am unable to get ACF to display on an archive page for the term itself.

```
    <?php the_field('download_link'); ?>
```

I added the above code to my theme and it doesn't work. I also tried

```
    <p><?php the_field('download_link', $term); ?></p>
```

Below is the default code on my page (content-archive.php). i'd like this to show up before.

```
    <div <?php post_class(); ?>>
<?php do_action( 'archive_post_before' ); ?>
<article>
    <div class='post-header'>
        <?php do_action( 'sticky_post_status' ); ?>
        <h2 class='post-title'>
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink() ); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        </h2>

        <?php get_template_part( 'content/post-byline' ); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="post-content">
        <?php ct_chosen_excerpt(); ?>
    </div>
</article>



<?php do_action( 'archive_post_after' ); ?>
```

Comment: Are you within [The Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop)? `the_field()` only works within the loop.

Comment: I am pasting that code before the code on (content-archive.php) page. Its on the first line. Is is possible to display an acf value on a archive page?

Comment: What is the value of `$term` in this case? You should be passing the id as the second parameter of `the_field()`.